# Получить предложение из номера строки Gutenberg corpus

Tags: python

Получил задачу на курсе, не могу решить.
У вас есть номер строки предложения в **whitman-leaves.txt** из корпуса Гутенберга. Распечатайте это предложение. 
Результатом должен быть список слов.

Мой вариант:

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg

sentences = gutenberg.sents("whitman-leaves.txt")

number = int(input() )#номер строки

print(sentences)
```

Comment: 1. что не так с этим вариантом? 2. Дай вопросу заголовок, отражающий твою проблему.

Comment: не получается получить информацию из номера строки

Comment: В этом коде нет даже намека на использование номера строки.

Comment: помогите. я только учусь

Comment: ну возьмите учебник

Comment: так можно тогда на каждый вопрос отвечать

Comment: На все нельзя. Только на те, где достаточно элементарных знаний.

Comment: для каждого уровня свое понятие элементарного